# Activity stack issue

Tags: android, android-activity

I have looked through stackoverflow here a lot and on internet...
There are several similar posts but whatever remedy they suggest isn't working for me...

i have activities as A->B->C->D->E. When i get to activity E, i have a button called exit and upon pressing it should exit the app altogether... or even on a back key press on activity E, it should exit app... i have tried following

```
    @Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK))
    { 
        this.finish();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

 public void onDestroy()
 {
        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Thanks for using App.\nGood Bye", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        //this.moveTaskToBack(true);
        //android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
 }
```

and have started my activity E from D as

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(Activity5.this, LastActivity.class); 
myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
startActivity(myIntent); 
finish();
```

but doesn't work for me... just activity E gets killed and D pops back up... I want application to exit totally from the screen and from the running processes.

But i would like the A->D keep working when the back key is pressed. Just when the use gets to E, i want to exit on the button click or back key...

any help will be appreciated.

i have also tried

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

on Activity A but no avail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can exit from the Activity E just overriding back button and going to the home ( like if you click Home Button ):

```
onBackPressed(){
    Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME); 
    startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(startMain);
    finish();
}
```

Comment: pablisco's solution is complex but more comprehensive but JackTruky's solution worked for me... just one question...

I have a class AppData extending Application
when the application starts again using launcher icon, the members or the AppData will be reinitialized... I think they would... but what you think...

Comment: i don't think because your application goes to background and will not be killed if you go on home. So onCreate method of AppData that extends Application will not be called again, but onResume will be called :)

Comment: I don't think this really does what you want. Once the user has clicked on "Exit" and he ends up on the HOME screen, he can long press on the HOME button (or go to the list of recent tasks) and select your application. It will now bring your application to the front and the user will see the last active activity there (I can't tell exactly which one, but I think it will show C since you've already finished D and E). Is this the behaviour that you want?

Comment: @DavidWasser you are right. But reading through different forums and stackoverflow about the activity lifecycle and force closing an app... recommendation is not to do so... What is your suggestion???

Answer (score 2):

A way I've found to do this is using a `BroadcastReceiver`. I tend to use it when I have activities that require the user to be logged in.

The fields I have in my base activity are these:

```
public static final String ACTION_LOGOUT = "com.app.android.ACTION_LOGUT";

private static IntentFilter logoutIntentFilter = new IntentFilter(
        ACTION_LOGOUT);

private BroadcastReceiver logoutBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i("Closing activity due to logout: "
                + BaseLoggedActivity.this.getClass());
        finish();
    }
};
```

and inside the `onCreate` (of the base activity) method I do this:

```
@Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    registerReceiver(logoutBroadcastReceiver, logoutIntentFilter);
}
```

And when I need to drop all the activities because of a logout I call this:

```
    this.sendBroadcast(new Intent(BaseActivity.ACTION_LOGOUT));
    this.finish();
```

Assuming `this` is an activity. It will send a broadcast to all the activities that are in the stack and let them finish gracefully, i.e. I have used a base activity on this example but you can provide a custom BroadcastReceiver where you may want to handle something before finishing the activity.

Comment: you don't think that this is a complex solution to reach what @Adi Gilani wants?

Comment: @JackTurky, yeah you are right, it seems like your solution  will suffice for this case. :) I guess my solution is more indicated if you want to have control over the finishing process of the activities.

Comment: Pablisco... Your solution is what was recommended to me by my teacher... but as JackTurky suggested, it is bit too complex for my needs... But thank you very much for the answer. I am pretty sure, i will use it in a future project....